# is having a module importing all Angular material modules tree-shakable?

Tags: angular

We usually create a module called `MyAngualarMatModule` and then import all `AngularMaterial` modules in `imports`, then in other modules if we need any Angular material compoments, we just import `MyAngualarMatModule`.

like below

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
    ],
})
export class MyAngualarMatModule { }
```

My question is is this approach make the project tree-shakable? for example if we have never used `MatTooltip` and we import it, does it includes in the final bundle?

Articles about being tree-shakable are discussing about angular services